# Two columns within a box

Tags: css

I am trying to place two blocks within a box using **CSS**. I have managed to do this with positioning the first column with `z-index`, but I am searching for a more elegant solution:

```
<style type="text/css">
   h3 {color: #990000; font-family: Lucida, Myriad, Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;     font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; }
   #main {float: auto; padding: 20px; margin: 0px; background:#eaeaea; max-width: 650px;}
   #box {width: float; height: float; background-color: white; padding: 8px 20px 30px    200px; border-radius: 10px;  box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0, 0.5);}
   #img {position: absolute; left: 60px; top: 85px; z-index: 2;}
</style>
<body>
   <div id ="main">
   <div id ="box">
   <div id = "img"> <img src="/images/bra.jpg" width="150" height="161" alt="test"></div>
   <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
   Lorem Ipsum är en utfyllnadstext från tryck- och förlagsindustrin.Lorem Ipsum är en     
   utfyllnadstext från tryck- och förlagsindustrin.Lorem Ipsum är en utfyllnadstext från tryck- och förlagsindustrin.Lorem Ipsum är en utfyllnadstext från tryck- och förlagsindustrin.Lorem Ipsum är en utfyllnadstext från tryck- och förlagsindustrin.Lorem Ipsum är en utfyllnadstext från tryck- och förlagsindustrin.Lorem Ipsum är en utfyllnadstext från tryck- och förlagsindustrin.
</body>
```

Thanks in advance for any clue!

Comment: `float: auto? width: float? height: float?` It should be a CSS newspeak?

Comment: Your CSS makes no sense, that might be the problem. Many properties you are attempting to use don't exist.

Comment: where were you close the main and box div??

Comment: I wonder if above code works!

Comment: @Gaurav: inexisting properties and values are ignored. So, nothing special it works, there rest only a few of this CSS.

Comment: Correct the code. At least specify your scenario correctly and clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have create css classes. Please check if it ll work.

JSFiddle: [click here](http://jsfiddle.net/creativehandz/y82vU/1/)

Thanks
Pranav

```
<style>
h3 {color: #990000; font-family: Lucida, Myriad, Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;     font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; }
   #main {border:1px solid red; padding: 20px; margin: 0px; background:#eaeaea; max-width: 650px; overflow:hidden;}
   #box {border:1px solid black; background-color: white; border-radius: 10px;  box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0, 0.5); padding:20px; overflow:hidden; display: table;}
   #img {border:1px solid brown;  width:39%; display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle; text-align:center; }
#content{border:1px solid brown; display: table-cell;  width:59%;}
</style>

<div id ="main">
   <div id ="box">
   <div id = "img"> <img src="/images/bra.jpg" width="150" height="161" alt="test"></div>
       <div id="content"><h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
   Lorem Ipsum är en utfyllnadstext från tryck- och förlagsindustrin.Lorem Ipsum är en     
   utfyllnadstext från tryck- och förlagsindustrin.Lorem Ipsum är en utfyllnadstext från tryck- och förlagsindustrin.Lorem Ipsum är en utfyllnadstext från tryck- och förlagsindustrin.Lorem Ipsum är en utfyllnadstext från tryck- och förlagsindustrin.Lorem Ipsum är en utfyllnadstext från tryck- och förlagsindustrin.Lorem Ipsum är en utfyllnadstext från tryck- och förlagsindustrin.</div> 
       </div>
       </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this solution?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pB9rU/

```
<style>
img {float: left;}
img ~ * {margin-left: 170px;}
</style>

<img src="/images/bra.jpg" width="150" height="161" alt="test">
<h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
<p>Lorem Ipsum är en utfyllnadstext från tryck- och förlagsindustrin.Lorem Ipsum är en utfyllnadstext från tryck- och förlagsindustrin.Lorem Ipsum är en utfyllnadstext från tryck- och förlagsindustrin.Lorem Ipsum är en utfyllnadstext från tryck- och förlagsindustrin.Lorem Ipsum är en utfyllnadstext från tryck- och förlagsindustrin.Lorem Ipsum är en utfyllnadstext från tryck- och förlagsindustrin.Lorem Ipsum är en utfyllnadstext från tryck- och förlagsindustrin.
<p>Lorem ipsum...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#main {
   background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #EAEAEA;
   margin: 0;
   max-width: 650px;
   padding: 20px;
}
#box {
   background-color: #FFFFFF;
   border-radius: 10px;
   box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
   padding: 8px 20px 30px 200px;
   position: relative;
}
#img {
   border: 1px solid;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 60px;
   padding: 25px 55px;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   z-index: 2;
}
```